# Test-service on Internet for testing incoming INVITE

Tags: sip, asterisk

I am trying to set up Asterisk at home.
I think I'm having trouble configuring my firewall, so that inbound traffic is accepted, but I am not sure.

I got the idea that, perhaps, there is a service out on the Internet, where I can, though a web-browser, initiate an incoming call, an INVITE. And then see the SIP-trace that the remote-part experience.

Anyone know of such a service?

Note. I have a SIP-PSTN provider so I can generate inbound calls. But I cannot see the SIP-logs from my provider...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get by using AIX or STUN/TURN/ICE.  more info on the latter here: http://www.voiptraversal.com/  Typically it is used to bypass NAT, but bypassing inbound firewall rules should be a happy side-effect as it is based on creating outbound connections and proxying relevant data that way.